# Add a link to the data explorer from the SOFU/StackExchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Please add a link to the data explorer from the main sites.  It should be somewhere that will show up consistently on every site, like the footer where all the sites are listed.  Preferably the link should skip the site selection page (choose the site where you clicked the link) and take you right to a query window.

The footer where all the other sites are listed seems like the best place.

Comment: The footer is getting kind of crowded. At a certain point, it will become too noisy. Sounds like they need some sort of menu-nav down there.

Comment: Maybe "league of justice" should come to an end for a better good. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I added it to the footer as "data".

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it's only necessary on [meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - maybe on the other sites' metas too.

But definitely a link would be nice.