# Add tool tips (alt text) to the links in the bottom nav on all sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, navigation

The SO, SF, SU, and Meta links (at least, and for consistency you'll want to add them to api/apps, careers, howtogeek.com, doctype.com, and [any](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53516/add-a-link-to-the-data-explorer-from-the-sofu-stackexchange-sites) [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51998/what-is-the-area-51-link) you add to the second row) should have tool tips (alt text) with their respective tags, as shown on the [homepage of SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) i.e. the text starting with "Q&A".